# Can anyone break this code down for me please?

Tags: python

Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order

```
spy_game([1,2,4,0,0,7,5]) --> True

spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) --> True

spy_game([1,7,2,0,4,5,0]) --> False
```

```
def spy_game(nums):
            code = [0, 0, 7, 'x']

            for num in nums:
                if num == code[0]:
                code.pop(0)      #code.remove(num) also works

        return len(code)==1      
        print(spy_game([1,2,4,0,1,0,7]))
```

Can anyone break this code down, especially this line:

return len(code)==1                      what does mean in this code ?

Comment: it will return `True` if length of the `code` equals to 1. In other way if it has exactly one element in list `code` it will return `True` otherwise `False`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing the title of your post?  As it is now, it's not very descriptive as to what kind of problem this is.

Answer (score 0):

```
def spy_game(nums):
        code = [0, 0, 7, 'x']
```

Defining a function, which takes in a list, for function purposes, it is called nums.
Then it defines a list code which has 007 in the order and a character which is sure to not appear in any of the sample list. For each number in the list

```
for num in nums:
            if num == code[0]:
            code.pop(0)
```

For each number in the list, if the number is same as the code's first number, it will pop it out.
if your nums is [1,0,6,0,7],

1. num = 1, num != code[0] which is 0. "next index"
2. num = 0, num == code[0] which is 0. "code[0] popped" "code is now [0,7,'x']
3. num = 6, num != code[0] which is 0. "next index"
4. num = 0, num == code[0] which is 0. "code[0] popped" "code is now [7,'x']
5. num = 7, num == code[0] which is 7. "code[0] popped" "code is now ['x']

As you can see, nums has been fully iterated and code length is only 1. Hence function returns true.

Comment: Thank you, you are the best.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it is correct and has helped you